# prove c f(n) is in theta f(n) for c>0

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

c f(n)  is in theta f(n) for c>0

I know that c is a constant, and if I can prove c f(n) is in big O(f(n) and in big Omega f(n) simultaneously, it is also in theta f(n), but how can I prove? I got confused.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question correctly: You are asking how to prove that `c f(n)` is `O(f(n))` and `Ω(f(n))`, that is, a constant multiplied by a function is big-theta of the function itself?

Answer (score 1):

`c f(n)` is `O(f(n))` because there is a constant k such that :

`|c f(n)| ≤  k |f(n)|` as `n -> infinity`

Hence, `|c| |f(n)| ≤ k |f(n)|`

dividing both sides by `|f(n)|` we get `|c| ≤ k`

So, any value of `k` larger than `|c|` would satisfy this condition. Therefore, `c f(n)` is `O(f(n))`

You can use the same method to show that `c f(n)` is also `Ω(f(n))`, and therefore it is `ϴ(f(n))`